# RecycleView not scrolling

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, scroll, android-constraintlayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/bottomSheetLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_top_round_corner">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardViewInnerProductContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    app:cardElevation="10dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/closeIv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_close_dark"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/changeAddressTitleTv"
            style="@style/FontLocalizedBold"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="7dp"
            android:paddingStart="12dp"
            android:text="@string/changeaddress_popup_change_address"
            android:textColor="@color/colorTextPrimary"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/closeIv" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/divider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/colorDividerLight"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/closeIv" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/locationRv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:paddingLeft="12dp"
            android:paddingRight="12dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/divider"
            tools:listitem="@layout/item_choose_address" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/addressesRv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:paddingLeft="12dp"
            android:paddingRight="12dp"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/locationRv"
            tools:listitem="@layout/item_choose_address" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>



        val addressesLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        addressesLayoutManager.orientation = RecyclerView.VERTICAL
        addressesRv.layoutManager = addressesLayoutManager
```

`addressesRv` recycleView is not scrolling.  I have this set in a bottomsheet dialog. It is just taking the 200dp height size and show only the items that fit, and I can not scroll through all items.

I have tried to take out the `CardView`, to remove the other recycle in the view, to wrap `addressesRv` inside a NestedScrollLayout, but neither one of the cases the scroll worked.

EDIT:

[image]

Comment: Have you done _recyclerview.setNestedScrolling(false)_ for RecyclerView?

Comment: @Piyush yes, no effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you put NestedScrollview, remove it.

And add this in your addressesRv recyclerview

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
```

Comment: If you put NestedScrollview,  remove it.

Comment: please edit your response and add also this comment, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using multiple `Recyclerview` in same page and i think both `recyclerView` has LinearLayout manager with vertical orientation. I found your first recycler view height is `wrapContent` but second one is fixed. So here it has a change scrolling problem. So here you need `nestedScrolview`.

**What `nestedScrollView` will do?:**

**Ans**: It will help you to scroll both recyclerview.

More discussion about Problem: 
Suppose your first recyclerView has 10 element and these element cover full screen but your second recyclerView has also 10 element. Now both recyclerView not shwoing all element together. Because the cannot scroll without `nestedScrollView`

**Code sample:**

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardViewInnerProductContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    app:cardElevation="10dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp">

 <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
       // Your other code
  </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
  </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: I want the first recycle to be fixed, it always has two elements. first all the area was scrollable, then came a request to make first two fixed. As i said i tried to remove one recycle, but the same result, not scrolling.

I have wrapped `addressesRv` inside a `NestedScrollView` but no effect

Comment: You have tou use nestedScrollView After CardView.

Comment: can you post a xml sample?

Comment: After the card view wrap constraint layout inside nestedScrollView

Comment: it is working only in one direction. if i want to scroll down, it closes the bottom sheet, even if the list has not reached the top yet.

Comment: So set recyclerView bottom to bottom parent and set height 0dp and keep nested scrollView

Comment: Because you miss bottom to bottom parent. app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"

Comment: I have added bottom also

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197026/discussion-between-tariqul-islam-and-ghita).

Answer (score 0):

**try this Place your constraint layout in CoOrdinator Layout**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you add class in your RecyclerView? You must set LayoutManager in class. Example:

```
recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(1,StaggeredGridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL));
```